# Emoji Remove from the specific column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to just remove emoji from one column and sepecial charater for eg (@ #.:/,.). Will remain in that specific column ?

I want to clean the data

Comment: Please read [ask] and [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples). We require sample data, the desired output, and your attempt at producing the desired output.

Comment: what is a "sepecial charater"?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove emojis from your data columns using the following code

```
df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.encode('ascii', 'ignore').str.decode('ascii'))
```